# How to insert data json in database laravel?

Tags: ajax, laravel

I use a jquery and ajax to get data json and send it to my controller, now I want to insert this data into table pointages help me please.
here is jquery ajax code:

```
  $('.add-all').on('click', function() {
        var items = [];
        let valu = $('#datePicker').val();
      $("tr").each(function(i,r){
        if ( i > 0 && $(r).find("input").first().prop("checked"))
        {  
          items.push({"matricule": r.cells[3].innerText, "salaire": r.cells[5].innerText, "date" : valu })
              }
                                      });
//ajax
$.ajax({ 
        method      : 'POST', 
        url       : 'mois', 
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
        data      : {"items":items}, // pass in json format 
        success   : function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error : function(err){
            console.log(err)
        }
    });

//fin ajax 
      });
```

Controller :

```
   public function addMultiple(Request $request){
      $data = $request->only('datep','salaire','matricule');
      $pointage['data'] = json_encode($data);
      Pointage::insert($pointage);

  }
```

---

i get :

```
 data: {…}
    items: (3) […]
    0: Object { matricule: "1", salaire: "6000", date: "2019-06-23"}
    1: Object { matricule: "2", salaire: "5000", date: "2019-06-23"}
    2: Object { matricule: "3", salaire: "7000", date: "2019-06-23" }
    length: 3
    <prototype>: Array [
    <prototype>: {…
```

---

model Pointage:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Pointage extends Model
{
    //
}
```

table pointages

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('pointages', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('matricule');
            $table->date('datep');
            $table->double('nbrj');
            $table->double('prime');
            $table->double('solde');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Comment: Do you have data in your `$data` variable? Can you `dd($data)`?

Comment: no ,i have items[]

Comment: if i put this code in my controller "return response()->json(['data' => $request->all()]);" i get my data in console

Comment: So you can `dd($request->all())` and see what you get from ajax. Then you can explain how you need to save your data. You can provide your model and migration for `Pointage`.

Comment: data: {…}
​​
items: (3) […]
​​​
0: Object { matricule: "1", salaire: "6000", date: "2019-06-23" }
​​​
1: Object { matricule: "2", salaire: "5000", date: "2019-06-23" }
​​​
2: Object { matricule: "3", salaire: "7000", date: "2019-06-23" }
​​​
length: 3
​​​
<prototype>: Array []
​​
<prototype>

Comment: Great you have data in your controller so you need to go through `foreach($request->items as $item)` and add `item` to your table. You can update your question with your model and migration, and I will try to solve your problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195443/discussion-between-najib-marzouk-and-mare96).